# How to ensure a file is completely ignored by git?

Tags: git

After each run of my Rails test suite, RSpec persists the status of all tests to spec/examples.txt.

This means that if I `git commit` my staging branch and then later run tests, examples.txt is modified even if I make no other file changes.

```
=> git checkout master
= error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    spec/examples.txt
```

I only care about examples.txt immediately after running a test, and am happy for these changes to be overwritten.

How can I force git to ignore examples.txt and not raise this error.

My `.gitignore` file includes `spec/examples.txt`.

I have run `git rm --cached spec/examples.txt`.

What additional steps should I take to ensure git ignores changes to examples.txt?

Answer (score 2):

you can instruct git not to care for it with update-index

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged the-file
```

And this is a per-repo command. Other developers will have to run it as well if they want the same behavior

Comment: That can and often will still leave complaints about the file being overwritten by `git checkout`. The problem is that the file is *committed* in the tip commit of `master`, so `git checkout master` is obliged to replace the work-tree copy of the file—even if it's not in the index now—with the master copy.

Comment: Yea.... I understand the implications. There's no silver bullet for some situations